# CasperJS include testfile dynamically in a loop with require or other function

Tags: javascript, loops, casperjs, require

I got a question respective extended testing in loops. I have a 3 leveled Loopstructure, where I have **URLs**, **Testfiles** and **Viewportsizes** like the following:

```
var navigation = [
  "http://www.url_1.com",
  "http://www.url_2.com",
  "http://www.url_3.com",
  "http://www.url_4.com"
];

var testfiles = [
  "/componenttests/atoms/test_dropdown_buttons.js",
  "/componenttests/atoms/test_conditional_buttons.js",
  "/componenttests/atoms/test_icon_buttons.js"
];


var viewPortsizes = [
  [1440, 900],
  [320, 480],
  [320, 568],
  [600, 1024],
  [1024, 768],
  [1280, 800]
];
```

And now I want to test this according to the following strategy:

**Run all TESTS on ALL URLs with ALL VIEWPORT SIZES**

Implemented in the following structure:

```
casper.start().then(function(){

  /* Loop through all URLs so that all are visited  */
  casper.eachThen(navigation, (function(response){

    var actUrl = response.data;

    /* Test different viewport resolutions for every URL */
    casper.eachThen(viewportSizes, function (responseView) {

      var actViewport = responseView.data;

      /* Set the viewport */
      casper.then(function () {            
        casper.viewport(actViewport[0], actViewport[1]);
      });

      /* Open the respective page and wait until its opened */
      casper.thenOpen(actUrl).waitForUrl(actUrl, function () {


        /* Single tests for every resolution and link */
        casper.each(testfiles, function (self, actTest, i) {

          /* AND HERE THE PROBLEM IS LOCATED, REQUIRE() ONLY WORKS ONCE */
          casper.then(function(){
            require('.' + testfiles[i]);
          });
        });
      });
    }));
})
.run(function() {
  this.test.done();
});
```

As commented in the code, the problem is that I can include / load these Testfiles only ONCE with require.

So what can I do here, I need to load the testfiles multiple times plain in the most inner loop.

The testfiles are only snippets like

```
casper.then(function () {
  casper.waitForSelector(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='Bla']"),
    function success() {
      DO GOOD STUFF
    },
    function fail() {
      BAD THIGNS HAPPENED
    });
});
```

At the moment in first run the file is included, and in all other runs > 1 nothing is included, the loops are run correctly but require does not work.

It is definitely the require functionality, because when I copied the testcode from the file directly into the loop it worked for multiple times too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

- Write your components as proper modules and require them at the beginning of your script or
- read the component test file and `eval` it.

#### Proper Modules

You can define your test components for example as

```
exports.test = function(){
    casper.then(function () {
        ...
    });
};
```

Then you can require them at the beginning:

```
testfiles = testfiles.map(function(path){
    return {
        path: path,
        test: require("." + path).test
    }
});
```

and use them directly in the test harness:

```
casper.then(function(){
    testfiles[i].test();
});
```

#### Evaluate on every turn

Or you can simply use this in your test harness without changing your test components:

```
var fs = require("fs");
...
casper.then(function(){
    eval(fs.read("."+testfiles[i]));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Artjom, i will test it ASAP now.

Comment: Hi Artjom, both solutions worked fine, thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: I went stright to the 2nd option and worked. Thank you.